# How to display an array at random?

Tags: php

I was wondering how I display a array at random here's my code

```
<?php
$names=file('name.txt');
echo count($names).'<br>';
foreach($names as $name)
?>

<h1>Random Names Test, Name: <?php echo $name.'<br>'; ?>
```

I know the code isn't 100% right to do the array at random :/ sorry I'm not that well at php but I want it to display random like if they reload the page another string from the text file will appear

Here I'll show you what I mean

```
<h1>Random Names Test, Name: Alim</h1>
```

When they reload the page another name will appear

```
<h1>Random Names Test, Name: Tiara</h1>
```

And also I don't know if they can see the array names in inspect element, if they can how can I prevent them from seeing them?

Comment: hint : use shuffle function http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_shuffle

Comment: try my answers @Alim Qureshi

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the function array_rand. This picks a random entry from an array.

**array.txt** (With Random Spaces)

```
   Test2 

   Test3 
   Test4 
   Test5 

   Test6 

   Test7 

   Test8
```

**Your PHP file**

```
<?php
    $names=file('array.txt');

    $fileArray = array_values(array_filter($names, "trim"));

    $text = array_rand($fileArray);
    $randomText = $fileArray[$text];
?>

<h1>Test: <?php echo $randomText; ?></h1>
```

[array_rand()](http://php.net/array_rand)

Comment: Actually I have to edit this because it is in a foreach loop.

Comment: It didn't work... It only displayed the first Letter of the name that was in the text file :/

Comment: How is your file written?

Comment: Yes I would like to see how the contents of your text file is written.

Comment: This is my text file: Alim Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6 Test7 Test8

Comment: I'm guessing because of the  `'<br>'` in the php code but what do I rplace that with?

Comment: no thats ok. Double quotes would be better though. also that was probably the 19 you were getting. 19 items in your array

Comment: actually this should be fine... works for me i just tested it.

Comment: ok the double quotes worked but it showed it in the wrong spot + it also showed the blanks -_- looks here's a gif: http://imgur.com/uQtMnoL

Comment: Ok so in the text file every line that you write is a new item in the array so make sure you dont have any extra skipped lines or blank spaces

Comment: But how do I make the 19 go away? I did not put it there the arrays supposed to be behind the `test:`

Comment: yes you did you said echo count($names).'<br>'; if you read it good you are echoing the number of items in the array. That is what the "count" function is for.

Comment: so you a basically counting the number of items in the array and showing the number. Just remove that line.

Comment: Ohhh but I removed that line but it still is showing in the wrong spot... here's the code I have `<?php$names=file('name.txt');$text = array_rand($names);echo $names[$text];?><h1>test: <?php echo $name[array_rand($name)]; ?></h1>` and here's the result: http://imgur.com/8kvKqCz

Comment: This code is messed up. What is your level of PHP? I can tell by the question you are asking but I still want to know..

Comment: <?php $names=file('name.txt');$text = array_rand($names);?><h1>test: <?php echo $names[$text]; ?></h1> ... echo means to show so when you echo something you print it to the screen

Comment: This is where I started learning PHP  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUV3iv9xOs&list=PL442FA2C127377F07   you should check it out its really good.

Comment: I'm a beginner :/ soz

Comment: really dude i helped you out so long and even explain how things work and you give the guy who gave you the fish? I thought you how to fish bro..

Comment: and yeah i can tell I fixed it for you three comments up didn't you see?

Comment: Yea but how could I do it if my txt file had spaces in it? Like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/JcqV6FJ0

Comment: I know it's possible

Comment: Ok i got it ... since you are a beginner i will update my answer fully

Comment: I'm a beginner but I've been working with php for a couple months now so I know some functions

Comment: @AlimQureshi I updated it so you can just copy and paste.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll test this out and sorry for the late reply

Comment: but I also have one more question if that's ok

Comment: what if my text file was http://pastebin.com/raw/LgVUyMaZ how would I display both 'Alim` and `Qureshi` but `Alim` is under `Qureshi` like this `<h1>Alim</h1><h1>Qureshi</h1>`

Comment: Is this the exact file? .. why are the other test written that  way?

Comment: Yes it's the exact file but they're written like this so they are displayed under each other like this: http://imgur.com/fMiLHKR I wanted them to be displayed under each other like in that image

Comment: but the problem is I don't know how to display them at the same time :/

Comment: Ok just a sec... btw if this answers your question better as I included the method for ignoring the blank lines you can mark it as the answer

Comment: Ok There is a better way to do this but for the sake of simplicity and since you said the file is exactly like that...

Comment: <?php
    $names=file('array.txt');

    $fileArray = array_values(array_filter($names, "trim"));
    $randomText = $fileArray[0];
    $randomText .= $fileArray[1];
?>

<h1>Test: <?php echo $randomText; ?></h1>

Comment: Hey, sorry I had to move so I couldn't reply till I got internet again but the last one you put doesn't work well it does it just doesn't display it at random it only displays the first two lines :/

Answer (score 0):

Google "random array php", first result: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
$key = array_rand($names)
```

It's even faster than posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file should be

**nn.txt**

```
   Test2 
   Test3 
   Test4 
   Test5 
   Test6 
   Test7 
   Test8
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php

    $names=file('nn.txt');
    echo count($names).'<br>';

    ?>
    <h1>Random Names Test, Name: <?php echo $names[array_rand($names)]; ?></h1>
```

Comment: space between line or text ?